# Is it possible to remove/uninstall Quicktime Player 7?

Tags: quicktime

Is it possible to remove/uninstall Quicktime Player 7?  I installed it back when my system was running Snow Leopard and now I'm on Mountain Lion I no longer need it but I can't see a way to remove it.

Comment: What happens if you drag it from the Applications folder to the Trash? (Back up your system first, in case you do, in fact need it!)

Answer (score 1):

OS X seems to allow just moving it to the trash, which is probably the recommended way to remove it.

If you use an application like [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), check that it doesn't actually try to delete files for the new QuickTime Player:

[image]

The bundle identifiers of the old and new version are `com.apple.QuickTimePlayer` and `com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX`. The only files it found for the old version were:

- `/Applications/Utilities/QuickTime Player 7.app/`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.quicktimeplayer.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.quicktimeplayer.plist.lockfile`
- `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.helpd/Generated/com.apple.QuickTimePlayer.help/`